# apache rewrite rule with query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect a existing url with three dynamic parameters values.
My existing url is like :

```
http://localmach.test.it:90/aa/nonLoggedUser.portal?appb=true&event=AppEvent&Code=1.564&mobile=789754654&locale=en
```

Now I want to redirect it to different ip with same parameters like :

```
http://17.22.11:90/aa/mycare?appb=true&event=AppEvent&Code=1.564&mobile=789754654&locale=en
```

I'm using apache url redirect in httpd.conf file.
I'm able to redirect url without parameters, but fail to redirect with parameters present.

I have tried below rewrite in httpd.conf but its not working

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
  ServerName localmach.test.it
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Code=([0-9]*)&mobile=([0-9]*)&locale=([a-z]*)$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)(aa/nonLoggedUser.portal?appb=true&event=AppEvent&)(.*)$ http://17.22.11:90/aa/mycare?appb=true&event=AppEvent&Code=%1&mobile=%2&locale=%3$

</VirtualHost>
```

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parameter `Code` is not the first one in query string so `^` before it won't match
2. You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` pattern.
3. Also regex for matching query parameters is also not correct.
4. You cannot use regex in target URI so `$` is treated a literal `$` there.

You can use this refactored rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(Code=[^&]*&mobile=[^&]*&locale=[^&]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?aa/nonLoggedUser\.portal$ http://17.22.11:90/aa/mycare?appb=true&event=AppEvent&%1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```